# Why static route can be ignored?

Tags: routing, openvpn, mikrotik, routeros

I'm trying to route all traffic to 10.2.0.0/24 via OpenVPN client(10.7.0.2)

```
Flags: X - disabled, A - active, D - dynamic, C - connect, S - static, r - rip, b - bgp, o - ospf, m - mme, B - blackhole, U - unreachable, P - prohibit 
 #      DST-ADDRESS        PREF-SRC        GATEWAY            DISTANCE
 0 ADS  0.0.0.0/0                          10.33.92.1                1
 1 ADC  10.1.0.0/24        10.1.0.1        bridge                    0
 2 A S  10.2.0.0/24                        10.7.0.2                  1
 3 ADC  10.7.0.2/32        10.7.0.1        openvpn1                  0
 4 ADC  10.7.0.9/32        10.7.0.1        openvpn1                  0
 5 ADC  10.33.92.0/24      10.33.92.196    ether1                    0

[root@gw1] /ip route> /tool traceroute 10.2.0.1
 # ADDRESS                          LOSS SENT    LAST     AVG    BEST   WORST STD-DEV STATUS                                                                                                                                                               
 1                                  100%    1 timeout                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 2                                  100%    1 timeout                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 3                                  100%    1 timeout
```

Where I'm wrong? Why ROS does not choose 10.7.0.2 to go through?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried setting PREF-SRC "10.7.0.1" then tracerouting?

Comment: @Arash, Yes, I have. Same result.

Comment: How do you know that it's not trying to go via 10.7.0.2? It could be a firewall blocking rule either on your Mikrotik or on the other end of the OpenVPN tunnel too.

Answer (score 0):

You may have configured subnet 10.2.0.0/24 on some bridge or interface.
Please attach yours `/ip address print` to the question.